# MacBook Pro 16 inch heating up when connected to an external display

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, gpu, macbook, temperature

I saw this question on other forums but I have yet to find an answer. I just bought a MacBook Pro 16 inch and for development I usually use a second monitor. However, I noticed that when I connect it to my monitor a Pavilion 27xw the surface gets hot and checking the temperatures I saw the average temp is 60 degrees Celsius at 97% cpu idle and the gpu around 70. This is the average temps not running any other app and I am doubtful how it will handle over time since heat can damage the components. I wonder if there is a solution to this issue or if there is any other laptop to consider. I chose apple for how reliable people say they are but this is concerning. I like to run dual monitors so clam shell is not a solution that I consider.

Comment: It will always run hotter with a 2nd display connected. So long as the cooling kicks in correctly it should be no issue.

Comment: I see, the thing is that if I put minimal stress on it the temperatures increases

Comment: To what? ProcHot on a modern CPU is about 100°C so if you're reaching that & the fans aren't kicking in, then it's time to worry. We don't have enough info to go on at the moment.

Comment: Temps stay 60-65 with no apps open just sitting on my desk but if I try to have something  done that stresses the CPU over 10% (-90% idle) then it heats up more and the fans are loud. My concern is long term and not so much the cpu but rather the surrounding parts which can get affected by heat.

Comment: the machine is doing what it's meant tod do. You're putting additional stress on it by adding a 2nd display. It has more work to do. The fans ramp up to compensate. That's how it's meant to work. If you really want big displays, don't use a laptop. They're not as fast or rugged as a big desktop. The price you pay for portability is slower operation & more heat.

Comment: Yes, I am aware but the GPU is consuming 15+ WATTs when it should be lower and the laptop lags at times so my original question is if there is any solution since that is not normal for a laptop. I had a 2 core spectre and it ran fine

Comment: I don't know what a "2 core spectre" is, nor do we actually know what your Mac is. Short answer is always - add another screen, ramp up your computer's activity/heat generation.

Comment: In the question I mention it is a Macbook pro 16 inch and a spectre x360 is an hp laptop